# How to add vertical spacing that is allowed to stretch for layout?

Tags: spacing, floats, vertical-spacing

I've got two images above each other in a figure environment, with `\vspace{1cm}` for spacing between them. I believe that if I had used two separate figure environments, LaTeX would have been able to shrink and grow the space a bit when optimizing the layout. However, here the spacing seems to be exactly 1cm. How can I achieve the stretchiness in a single figure environment?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}\centering%
    \rule{6cm}{4cm}
    \caption{Foo.}
    \vspace{1cm}
    \rule{6cm}{4cm}
    \caption{Bar.}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-8]
\end{document}
```

The reason I'm using a single figure environment is that I want the two figures above each other, on the same page.

Comment: @Anna what is your definition of optimize the layout?

Comment: @yannisl If I understand correctly, LaTeX e.g. adds spacing between paragraphs to avoid orphans. Is that right?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you, that's great. So I can write `\vspace{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}`. What's the best way to figure out how much stretching is normally allowed between two figure environments?

Comment: @Anna In your case you only have one figure, which is what you want to include probably two pictures and two captions. This is treated as a single box and LaTeX/TeX will add some glue on top or bottom. It will not stretch the two pictures to fill a page or something like that. My suggestion, rephrase your question to ask exactly why you need and please since you using memoir  texoc menman  Is a very good resource.

Comment: @yannisl Sorry, I'll try to explain. In my question I intended each `\rule` to represent one included graphic (what I called figure). In the code I pasted, the spacing between the figures is constant. However in other places LaTeX adds "stretchy"/glue space. I was wondering how to make that space stretchy/glue. What can I clarify? The memoir manual is indeed fantastic, I've read it in its entirety.

Comment: @Anna  The figure environment, will not adjust its height based on what is surrounding it. Simplistically is a single `vbox`.  See pg 15 https://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/reports/2009/boxes.pdf  to see how vboxes are stacked.

Comment: @yannisl I don't quite understand, do you mean it is impossible to achieve what I'm asking for? I haven't verified samcarter's suggestion, do you think it will not adjust?

Comment: Yes. You can try and see. Best is to take the two images out of a float, then is possible. I.e. dont use the {figure} environment, if you want full control, but then you will be designing page by page like a graphic designer. I do this quite often for special page designs.

Comment: Thank you @yannisl! I understand now that it is not possible to let LaTeX handle the float positioning, while still forcing these two images to be on the same page with stretch/glue space between them.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

An easier solution is to use two [p] floats, but these don't take up enough space (see `\floatpagefraction`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \centering
    \rule{6cm}{4cm}
    \caption{Foo.}
  \vfil
    \rule{6cm}{4cm}
    \caption{Bar.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-8]
\end{document}
```